# CCNode/CCSprite/Box2D memory performance questions (cocos2d,iphone)

Tags: iphone, performance, memory, cocos2d-iphone, cpu

is it enough if I set the visibility to NO on my CCNode/CCSprite? Is it still in the memory?

What's the best way to remove it from memory and than put it again to it (fast)?

What about b2Body's? How to do that on them?

I want to do this because I splitted up my level and I just want to put the objects into memory which are visible....

Answer (score 2):

Setting a node/sprite to invisible will definitely not free it from memory.  If you want to remove it from memory completely and add it in again quickly I suspect a memory pool is the best way to do that.

I'm not sure I understand why you want to have only objects that are visible in memory and then be able to quickly add them into memory again quickly?  It's likely I just don't follow what you are trying to accomplish.  You may be trying to optimize your memory usage to prematurely.  Certainly you should stop all memory leaks but have you done any profiling as to how much memory your project is using?

Comment: the main problem is that if I have too many sprites/b2bodys my player body will be jerky and my ccfollow action will be jerky too because it's following the player...I made some tests and saw that if I don't have so much objects it's not jerky...

Comment: +1 for an idea. i will try this out tomorrow...(don't have any time today)